# How to prove if $^=^{−1}$, then $\det() = 1$ is indeed true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Statement:  If $^=^{−1}$, then $\det() = 1$

We know that if $A$ is an invertible matrix, then $\det(A^{−1})$ is equal to $\frac1{\det(A)}$.

Does this contain a same logic to the question above in proving in terms of the determinants?

Comment: If $A=(-1)$, you have $A^{T}=(-1)=A^{-1}$, but $\det(A)=-1$. You can prove that $\det(A)=\pm1$ follows from the assumptions. From $A^T=A^{-1}$, you get $A^TA=I$. Take determinants on both sides to get that $1=\det(I)=\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T)\det(A)=\det(A)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^{T} = A^{-1}$ then $A^TA = I$

Since $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$  and $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$

$\det(A^TA) = \det(A)^2 = \det(I)=1$

$\det(A) = \pm 1$

Comment: since det(A) both contain either a positive or negative one(1), then we can say that the given statement above in my question is false??? Since it only describes det(A) having only a positive one(1).

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. Take e.g. $$A = \left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0\\ 0& 1\end{matrix}\right),$$

then $A = A^{-1} = A^T$, but $\det A = -1$. The only thing that holds is $(\det A)^2 = 1$.